# jQuery picking out value but not showing/finding it within

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of **79** out of the example below:

[image]

And I figured that would be pretty easy to get but it doesn't seem that way. I have tried the following to extract the **79**:

```
console.log(width4);
console.log(width4["0"].clientWidth);
console.log($(width4).clientWidth);
console.log($(width4)[0].clientWidth);
```

Naturally the **console.log(width4);** shows me the tree that I have an image of above. I can see its there but for some reason this is the output of the above 4 console.log outputs:

```
>[td.jsgrid-cell.jsgrid-align-left]
jsgrid.js:511 0
jsgrid.js:512 undefined
jsgrid.js:513 0
```

[image]

So looking at that it seems that any of those I have used should at least see the value and not **0** or **undefined**?

Comment: width4[0].clientWidth ?

Comment: @sheplu still shows **0**

Comment: do you have something insde width4[0] ? or 0 too?

Comment: @sheplu look at my image of the tree.. It's there...

Comment: i see ! but the correct way is width4[0].clientWidth. that should output 79. So i want to be sure there is not error, and that width4[0] contains your data

Comment: How are you retrieving this data? API call? Jquery selector? Can you give code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a timing issue. Maybe you're accessing the properties before it's had a chance to render to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have tried

```
console.log(width4[0].clientWidth);
```

That should work